# Estimation of Molar Entropies

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

There are plenty of compounds out there with unknown standard molar entropies. I know that molar entropy has a strong dependance on the physical phase, molecular weight, and number of atoms. So is it feasible to use these parameters to roughly estimate the molar entropy of, for example, ammonium acetate?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is about; there are several dozens handbooks and databases of thermodynamic data, some are readily available, some are paid only, which list temperature-dependent molar entropies for thousands of compounds. Sure, there wasn't always so much data, but there was a huge gain in accumulating these parameters over the cold war period by both USA and USSR for the needs of rocket scientists. Is there a certain system or compound you are having difficulties finding molar entropy for?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm looking for the std molar entropy of ammonium acetate. This is a reoccurring problem for me, as I keep coming across compounds for which I cannot find the molar entropy. I don't mind if the database is paid-only, could you point me to a fairly large database. Or in this case, at least one which has the molar entropy for ammonium acetate?